# How to access objects from map?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions

I am mapping over an object and I am returning its values in the console perfectly fine.

```
  const editCritical = assetIdObject.map(item => {

    if(item.asset_id === criticalObjectsId)
    return {
      title: item.asset_id,
      domain: item.domains,
      type: item.type

    }
  })


  console.log(editCritical, 'from edit Critical');
```

returns me

[logged console values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYeyX.png)

However when I try to access it like this

console.log(editCritical[0].title, 'from edit Critical');

When I try and access the title it gives me undefined...How come its not letting me access the title of the object? and yes please ignore the domain being returned as undefined.

Comment: The only reason it would return undefined is if the `criticalObjectsId` does match any of the array item's `asset_id`. As you're only returning items if they match the `criticalObjectsId` and if it doesn't, it implicitly returns undefined

Comment: it loggs it fine when I log the whole object which returns me the items assset_id  and the rest of the properties? as shown in the photo above

Answer (score 0):

According to my observations, your problem originates in map function.

By default, if nothing is returned in the current iteration of the map function, it will return undefined.

Therefore, since you only return content when the asset_id's are equal, some of your entries will be undefined.

ex:

```
[undefined, {title:'title', domain: undefined, type: 'orange'}, undefined]
```

This meaning that accessing editCritical[0].title has the possibility of returning undefined.

Basically what I am trying to say is that it seems your problem comes from the map function returning undefined. Since your return code is contained within a conditional statement there will be cases where nothing has been returned and it returns undefined by default.

Hopefully this helps

two ways of accessing an objects child

```
let obj = {title: 'my title', type: 'orange'};

// returns 'my title'
console.log(obj.title)

//returns 'orange'
console.log(obj['type'])
```